# Opera 11.50+ implementation of history.replaceState()

Tags: javascript, opera, browser-history

Consider this jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/maple/JbEJN/show/ (this is the result window, in order for replaceState to work, see [actual fiddle with code here: http://jsfiddle.net/maple/JbEJN/](http://jsfiddle.net/maple/JbEJN/)).

This is a simple javascript tab control. I click 'Tab 1' and see the contents of one div. I click 'Tab 2' to hide the div that was showing and show another one, with different content. You get the drill, standard tab control.

Now, what I **do** want is to use hashtags to be able to bookmark or link the page with a certain tab selected. What I **don't** want is to create a browser history entry each time I switch between tabs so that when I press back I have to circle through 10 tabs before I can actually go back to the page I came from.

The way I intend to implement this is by using replaceState() when I switch between tabs to insert a hashtag into the url of the page, like so:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, '', '#tabname');
```

What I expect to happen here is that no history entries are created when switching between tabs, so when I switch a few times between tabs I see the hashmark change, but when I hit the back button I just go back to the previous page (or nothing happens if I opened the test page in a new window).

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not Opera 11.50 and 11.60. As far as I know Opera claims to fully support the history API in Opera, but what happens in Opera is that replaceState() works like pushState(), entries get put into history.

Is this a bug in Opera, or should I use the API in some different manner in Opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what's happening here is that the click event's default action is to activate the link - so after you call replaceState() the default action will update the URL, add #tabname, and create a history entry. Try to use `event.preventDefault()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/JbEJN/8/show/

I'm not sure why your original code worked as intended in Chrome and Firefox. Presumably they do not create a history entry if replaceState() already updated the URL and the link's activation won't change it? If so, Opera should probably change to match them. Could you report this as an issue on https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ ? If you give me the bug reference ID I'll follow up.

Comment: You're correct, adding event.preventDefault() fixes the issue in Opera (and leaves things unchanged in other browsers). I've filed a bug, its id is DSK-355229.